# Are there uncountably many distinct group operations on an uncountable set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Call two group operations $\ast_1$ and $\ast_2$ on a set $S$ $distinct$ if there exist $s_1,s_2\in S$ such that $s_1\ast_1 s_2 \neq s_1 \ast_2 s_2$.

I know that there are uncountably many distinct group operations on any denumerable set. How might one show that the same is true for an uncountable set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. You can write any infinite set $A$ as $\Bbb N\times B$ where $B$ has the same cardinality as $A$. Fix any group operation on $B$ which is "simple enough" (e.g. torsion free, or even free [abelian] group of a suitable size), and then go over all the group operations you have on $\Bbb N$ as a countable set.

Finally, $A$ is the group you get by the product of these two groups. So you just need to show that there is an uncountable collection of choices for group structure on $\Bbb N$ which give you distinct group structure on $A$. (HINT: If you chose $B$ to be torsion free this is easy enough.)

(Of course this uses the axiom of choice, but then again the statement "Every non-empty set can be made into a group" is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so it's not surprising.)